# Lucene: how do I assign weights to the different search terms at query time?

Tags: lucene

I have a Lucene indexed corpus of more than 1 million documents.
I am searching for named entities such as "Susan Witting" by using the the Lucene java API for queries.
I would like to expand my queries by also searching for "Sue Witting" for example but would like that term to have a lower weight than the main query term.

How can I go about doing that?
I found infos about the boosting option in the Lucene Manual. But it seems to be set at indexing and it needs fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can boost each query clause independently. See the [Query Javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html#setBoost%28float%29).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give different weight to the words of a **term.** Then

`Query#setBoost(float)`

is not useful. A better way is:

```
Term term = new Term("some_key", "stand^3 firm^2 always");
```

This allows to give different weight to words in the same term query. Here, the word `stand` boosted by three but `always` is has the default boost value.